# MS Access 2016 Adding Values From Other Tables

Tags: ms-access

So I have two access tables:

Jobs Table:

**JobID**,
Customer,
Address,
Measure Date,
Install Date

Job Items:

**JobID**,
**Item Name**,
Item Length,
Item Width,
Item Quantity,
Item Cost

So what I want to do is add a field to the Jobs Table that shows the **Total Value** of all of the Item Costs with the same JobID.

How do I do this?

Edit:

Jobs:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
| ID |  Customer   |     Address     | Measure Date | Install Date |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 | Josh Manson | 22 Louis Lane,  | 13/08/2016   | 27/08/2016   |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Job Items:

```
+------------+-------------------------+-------------+------------+---------------+--------------------+
| Job Number |        Item Name        | Item Length | Item Width | Item Quantity | Item Material Cost |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------+------------+---------------+--------------------+
|          1 | Security Screen         |         800 |        600 |             2 | $250.00            |
|          1 | Window, white aluminium |         700 |        400 |             3 | $150.00            |
+------------+-------------------------+-------------+------------+---------------+--------------------+
```

I would like there to be an extra column in the first table that adds all the Item Costs for that ID. For JobID 1 it would have a value of $400.

Sorry I'm not quite sure how to format tables properly in StackOverflow.

Comment: Please [edit] to include sample data from both tables and the output you'd like to obtain from that data.

Comment: @KenWhite I have added some info

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a *running total*. That should give you something to search for here.

Comment: @KenWhite The running total looks good but how do I get the final total and move it to the other table?

Comment: As a rule, you don't store calculated data in tables. You should use a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query in the query designer, with both tables and their INNER JOIN.

Add functions/grouping by clicking the "Totals" button.

Add all fields from the Jobs table, they will all be set to "Group by".

Add `Item Material Cost` from the Items table, and set its "Total" to `Sum`.

That's it (well, you should set a column title for the sum column, or it will show in the query result as `SumOfItemMaterialCost` or something).